# Jetty 7.4.5 server leaking file descriptors when useFileMappedBuffer = true

Tags: java, linux, jetty, memory-leaks, memory-mapped-files

I am currently facing an issue with my java webapp running on Jetty 7.4.5.v20110725 on Linux. My Webapp serving static content is running out of file descriptors after a few days from its start timestamp. I am starting the jetty server with useFileMappedBuffer = true( in webDefaults.xml ) . I am using jdk1.6.0_30 . Please let me know if you'll have any suggestions on how to fix this issue.

Please note that this issue does not occur when useFileMappedBuffer = false (in webDefaults.xml).

Answer (score 0):

If your application has run out of timestamps next time, please try to find out which files are open and if open connections are causing a problem.

Try to list open files by calling (I think it's `lsof -p`, but try or look at the lsof manpage as I'm writing this out of my mind):

```
lsof -p <jettypid>
```

This will show you what files are opened by the jetty process. Look for files which probably should have been closed already, etc.

Then do a:

```
netstat -an
```

This will show you established network connections. Look if there's lots of connections in `CLOSE_WAIT` state or similar indicating that connections are not properly closed.

Also have a look at your system wide OS limits with:

```
ulimit -a
```

It'll show you how many file descriptors can be opened by a single process. If you've a site with high traffic and the pretty common default value of 1024 max fd, you might need to raise that. If you think that traffic is the problem have a look at this guide: http://wiki.eclipse.org/Jetty/Howto/High_Load

However you've stated that the problem does occur only after a couple of days. This usually indicates not properly closed connections, file resources, etc.

If unsure what to do with the output of the commands above, feel free to paste them.

Independent of the problem I'd recommend you to upgrade to the latest jetty 7.x.